# Calling text from between specific HTML tags to use as data for a variable in PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, bbcode

Trying to add more functionality to my gaming site that's running Invision Power Board software. It comes with the ability to add custom BBcode, and I'm trying to make a tag that can use the poster's item name and use PHP to pick out the correct item file and display it as html in place of the tag.

My question is, how do I take `[tag=option]` and plug the option into a PHP switch's variable to allow a poster to define the case? The software would turn `[tag=option]` into `<p><div id="item">{option}<br /><br /><?php switch goes here ?></div></p>`.

I've run around google searching through W3C and this site and other random places and I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem. Maybe I just don't know what I should be looking for. Please help?

Comment: If you're running invision, you shouldn't be doing this with plain PHP. I'm sure invision has a mechanism for creating either custom BBcodes or some sort of plugin (which is better suited to your use case) API. You should have a look at their docs

Comment: PHP has a BBCode extension for that: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to do this..... i did something similar on an ajax chatbox, changing

```
:lmao:
```

into

```
<img src="/smileys/lmao.png">
```

depending on your existing form script to display code.....

mine only needed a simple str_replace, but all site configs are different

can you edit your question, and paste your php code that displays the page you want the divs to appear on.....

thanks.

edit....
maybe i should have read date posted before answering pmsl